# using agSetColumnFilter with serverSide row model

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using `agSetColumnFilter` in my Angular app, I'm using `serverSide` row model. If I use `infinite` row model it works correctly. I'm passing array of values to filter.

The problem is that
**I can't change a state of checkboxes in filter element**.

If I click on one checkbox filters are applying with that one option, but it looks like the state of checkbox is changing to opposite immediately, and the state of filter doesn't save. I can choose only one category to filter.

```
<app-ag-grid  
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
  [pagination]="pagination"
  [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize" 
  [rowModelType]="rowModelType" 
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" 
  [context]="context" 
  [floatingFilter]="floatingFilter"
  [paginationAutoPageSize]="paginationAutoPageSize"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
  </app-ag-grid>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-side',
  templateUrl: './server-side.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-side.component.scss']
})
export class ServerSideComponent implements OnInit {
  paginationAutoPageSize = false;
  gridApi: GridApi;
  gridoptions;
  rowData;
  pagination = true;
  paginationPageSize = 100;
  rowModelType = 'serverSide';
  floatingFilter = false;
  defaultColDef = {
    sortable: false,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filter: true
  };
  enableServerSideSorting = true;
  enableServerSideFilter = true;
  columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'isActive',
      headerName: 'Active',
      cellRenderer: 'checkboxRenderer',
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      width: 100,
      filterParams: {
      values: [true, false]
  }
},
{
  field: 'balance',
  headerName: 'Balance',
  filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
  width: 100,
  type: 'numericColumn',
  filterParams: {
    filterOptions: ['equals', 'lessThan', 'greaterThan'],
    suppressAndOrCondition: true
  },
},
{
  field: 'tags',
  headerName: 'Tags',
  filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
  filterParams: {
    suppressRemoveEntries: true,
    values: (params) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        params.success([
          'id',
          'irure',
          'cillum',
          'nostrud',
          'pariatur',
          'laborum'
        ]);
      }, 500);
    }
  }
}
];
context = { componentParent: this };
frameworkComponents = {
  listRenderer: ListRendererComponent,
  checkboxRenderer: CheckboxRendererComponent,
  multiselectEditor: MultiselectEditorComponent,
  dateEditor: DateEditorComponent,
  richTextEditor: RichTextEditorComponent,
  agDateInput: DateFilterComponent
};
```

Comment: please share code snippet to debug easily

Comment: I would advice you to include some code you tried into your question. It will increase the changes of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `newRowsAction: 'keep'` to your `filterParams` object you should find that the state of the filter is retained when the checkboxes are deselected/selected. The docs are not clear in this regard (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided/#providedFilterParams) as they say the property is for use with Client Side row model only, but changing the filter causes the row data to be reloaded in server side mode, and this property 'keeps' the filters when that happens.

So, your tags field in columnDefs would be modified thus:

```js
{
  field: 'tags',
  headerName: 'Tags',
  filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
  filterParams: {
    newRowsAction: 'keep',
    suppressRemoveEntries: true,
    values: (params) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        params.success([
          'id',
          'irure',
          'cillum',
          'nostrud',
          'pariatur',
          'laborum'
        ]);
      }, 500);
    }
  }
}
```